# Difference between "have been practicing" and "have practiced"?

Tags: present-perfect, present-progressive

> - I *have been practicing* the piano for 2 years.
> - I *have practiced* the piano for 2 years.

Could you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: `I have been practicing the piano for 2 years.` is present perfect continuous and it means `you have started practicing piano 2 years ago and you are still continuing it.`

`I have practiced the piano for 2 years.` is present prefect and it means `you started practicing piano 2 years ago, and it doesn't specify whether you still continuing it or not.`